# Recycler view not displaying. It shows me the error as E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

There is no errors in adapter or any other classes. I attached a text view below this recycler view for testing and it displays nicely without recyclerview.

I am just passing a string array with two values as a parameter to the adapter class.

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private String[] dataset = {"One","Two"};

    private RecyclerView resview;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter madapter;

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mlayoutManager;
    private View view;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        initializeRecyclerView();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        mlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        resview.setLayoutManager( mlayoutManager);


        resview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.resview);

        madapter = new ReAdapter(dataset);

        resview.setHasFixedSize(true);

        resview.setAdapter(madapter);

        return view;
    }
    //Even without this initialize method, i am getting this same error
    void initializeRecyclerView() {
        resview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.resview);
        resview.setAdapter(new ReAdapter(dataset));
        resview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        resview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

   }
```

Here is the adapter class.

```
  public class ReAdapter extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<ReAdapter.Reviewholder> {


String[] dataset1;


public ReAdapter (String[] dataset){


    dataset = this.dataset1;


}



@Override
public Reviewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view =         LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclecontent,parent,false);
    Reviewholder holder = new Reviewholder(view);
    return holder;
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Reviewholder holder, int position) {

    holder.restext.setText(dataset1[position]);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataset1.length;
}

public class Reviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

public TextView restext;


public Reviewholder(View view) {

    super(view);

    restext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.restext);


}
}

}
```

Comment: post your code for adapter class as well

Comment: http://www.android-examples.com/android-simple-recyclerview-example-tutorial/

Comment: first you should remove the doubled recyclerView initialization. You do it twice, once in `initiualizeRecyclerView` after that later in `onCreateView()`

Comment: @RahulKhurana just now edited with adapter class

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Even without this initializeRecyclerView() method am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

change your constructor like below

```
public ReAdapter (String[] dataset){
     this.dataset1 = dataset;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    resview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.resview);

    mlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    resview.setLayoutManager( mlayoutManager);

    madapter = new ReAdapter(dataset);

    resview.setHasFixedSize(true);

    resview.setAdapter(madapter);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I changed but still the error appears and recyclerview is not displaying.

Comment: try removing resview.setHasFixedSize(true);

Comment: and comment initializeRecyclerView method call inside onCreateView

Comment: I commented both(hasfixedsize,initializeRecyclerview) but Still no changes sir.

Comment: Even after removing initializeRecyclerView() method am still getting error sir.

Comment: Yes sir..i tried your updated answer but still am getting that same error.

Comment: put a log of dataset1.length; inside getCount() method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView resview;
    private ReAdapter madapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager mlayoutManager;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        resview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        resview.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mlayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        resview.setLayoutManager(mlayoutManager);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        String[] dataset = {"One", "Two"};
        madapter = new ReAdapter(dataset);
        resview.setAdapter(madapter);

    }

    class ReAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReAdapter.Reviewholder> {

        String[] mDataset;

        public ReAdapter(String[] collection) {

            mDataset = collection;
        }

        @Override
        public Reviewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclecontent, parent, false);
            return (new Reviewholder(view));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(Reviewholder holder, int position) {
            holder.restext.setText(mDataset[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDataset.length;
        }

        public class Reviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView restext;


            public Reviewholder(View view) {

                super(view);
                restext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.restext);

            }
        }

    }
  }
```